# how to add a sample image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

I have simple rails website where people can post a shipment with an image and for that i use `paperclip` gem but my problem is if a user added a shipment without uploading an image, it's get posted but with no image but what i want is to add a sample image so that if somebody added a shipment without an image there will automatically an sample image

**My code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="post_show">
  <h1>
    <strong><font style="text-transform: capitalize;"><%= @shipment.name %></strong></font>
  </h1>
  <p></p>
  <p class="username">
    Added by
    <strong><font style="text-transform: capitalize;"><%= @shipment.user.full_name %></strong></font>
    about
    <%= time_ago_in_words(@shipment.created_at) %>
  </p>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="post_image_description">
      <%= image_tag @shipment.image.url(:medium) %>
      <div class="description">
        <%= simple_format(@shipment.description) %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image, label: "Add An Image Of The Shipment" %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#user-content-models

There is an option of `default_url` in case image is not uploaded then as default image it takes `/images/:style/missing.png` you can also specify your own specific image path over there to display as default image.

Here is sample taken from paperclip documentation (**Rails 4**):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**OR**

You can display with condition like:

```
<%= image_tag @shipment.image.url.present? ? @shipment.image.url(:medium) : "your_default_image.png" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify missing image path in paperclip using option `default_url`

model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/images/normal/missing.png"
```

Comment: have you putted default image in public folder `images/normal` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Use default_url so it always has an image.  it is an option of paperclip